# What is the physical meaning when we say complex waveform has an energy at certain frequency?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, frequency

We say that a complex periodic wave has an energy at certain frequencies.

Or we can also say that such waveform has a certain “frequency component”.

I understand that mathematically it means we can extract this frequency component from our initial complex waveform using Fourier transform.

But what is the physical meaning of this?

Say we have an *almost* pure electromagnetic square wave at $2000$Hz traveling through vacuum.
Mathematics tells us that this wave has an energy at frequency $6000$Hz.

What does it mean physically if this wave doesn’t interact with anything?

Is this a fundamental physical property of the wave or just the way we look at it with mathematics?

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate of your previous question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594234/74763

Comment: I was thinking of deleting that question because the phrasing there isn’t the best. Btw your answer first appeared and then vanished (probably cache issue). What would you recommend? In my opinion, “energy” terminology is better to understand this topic.

Comment: Actually, I deleted my answer to the other question, and then I undeleted it after seeing that nobody else was venturing an answer. I'm not terribly good at physics, so normally I shy away from "answering" anything. I'll be interested to see whether your question ignites any controversy over the "true physical meaning" of Fourier transforms.

Comment: I’ll leave it for now in respect of your answer. If mods decide to delete one of them, so be it.

Comment: I asked once a related question but received no answer. (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560064/195949). I think that EM waves are not necessarily sinusoidal, but interaction with matter (prisms, diffration gratings...) generates sinusoidal waves from the source. If there is a proof that they must be present necessarily for all EM waves, I don't know.